# Not getting Address from latitude and longitude

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am using following code for get address from current latitude and longitude, But I am not able to get proper response

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{

    current_latitude=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    current_longitude=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if(placemarks && placemarks.count > 0)
        {
            CLPlacemark *placemark= [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString * address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@,%@ %@", [placemark subThoroughfare],[placemark thoroughfare],[placemark locality], [placemark administrativeArea]];

            UIAlertView *art = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:address message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [art show];
            [art release];
            NSLog(@"%@",address);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, when you say you are not getting correct response! We have n idea what response you are getting. So please elaborate! Tell us what you were expecting and what did you got! Is your own code breaking?

Comment: I am getting data in [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];, but as per doc,when i fetch data using [placemark locality], then i m getting null. All data are come in [placemarks objectAtIndex:0]; which is correct but not getting proper when use locality.

Answer (score 0):

`CLLocation` has poor coverage at the moment; see [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2289/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011305). It's possible you're trying to geocode a location from a poorly covered area.

If that's the case, there are other geocoders, such as [Google's Geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) (which requires you to display the results on a map).